# Field Calculator not working in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I am having a problem with Field Calculator in ArcGIS Desktop 10. I wonder if there is a known fix at this point. I'm updating to 10.1 soon, but this work cannot wait until then.

I am trying to divide two fields and then multiply the answer by 100 into a calculated field. I have created a field to receive the answers, "Grad_Per". I highlight the [Grad_Per] field, right click, select Field Calculator, and enter [elev_range]/[SLength]*100. Answers then populate the Grad_Per field down to record number 564 but no further. The answers up to that point are correct; I've checked them in MS Excel and by hand. It's just that I've got about 9500 more records to calculate and they have values of 0 after the calculation is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `[SLength] = 0` in record number 565, it is a division by zero error.

I'm not sure why the software didn't return an error message, and why it calculated all subsequent values as 0. Probably worth a bug report to Esri. I don't know if setting SLength to "Null" instead of 0 will avoid this.

Regardless, if you select all the rows where [SLength] is not 0 then perform the calculation, you will get results in all possible rows.